# Is it needed to create a new channel each time I need to refresh the JWT token?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I have a gRPC service and to avoid to have to pass the token in each method call, I am add the the JWT token when I create the channel. I am using this code:

```
private GrpcChannel GetCanal(string paramStrDireccion, int paramIntPuerto, string? paramStrTokenJwt = null)
{
    SocketsHttpHandler miHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
    miHttpHandler.SslOptions.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(miHttpHandler);

    GrpcChannelOptions misOpcionesDelCanal = new GrpcChannelOptions()
    {
        MaxReceiveMessageSize = 62914560,
        MaxSendMessageSize = 62914560,
        HttpClient = httpClient,
    };

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paramStrTokenJwt) == false)
    {
        CallCredentials misCredenciales = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((c, m) =>
        {
            m.Add(HeaderNames.Authorization, $"Bearer {paramStrTokenJwt}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

        misOpcionesDelCanal.Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), misCredenciales);
    }


    


    try
    {
        Uri miUri = new Uri(paramStrDireccion + ":" + paramIntPuerto.ToString());
        GrpcChannel miCanal = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(miUri, misOpcionesDelCanal);
        return miCanal;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The data of the server aren't correct.");
    }
}
```

But if I am not wrong, the creation of the channel is one of the most expensive process in the communication, so I am wondering if it there would be some way to update the token of the channel without creating a new channel when I need to update the JWT token becuase it expired it.

Thanks.

Comment: You're right that you should not recreate a channel too often (but if the JWT token has lifetime e.g 1 hours, the overhead associated with recreating channels will be negligible for all practical purposes).  

Note that you can attach the "metadata" credentials (the ones that add a auth metadata entry to each call) not just to a channel but also on per-call basis. So the solution would be to simply create channel with plain SslCredentials, and then apply CallCredentials to each call (which would add the authentication token to the call just as well).

Comment: Note that when you apply CallCredentials to a a composite channel credentials via e.g. `ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), misCredenciales);`, it basically does the same thing under the hood as applying the call credentials to each call separately.